# Most efficient way to check if a point is in or on a convex quad polygon

Tags: testing, geometry, polygon

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient/fast way to add a large number of convex quads (four given x,y points) into an array/list and then to check against those quads if a point is within or on the border of those quads.

I originally tried using ray casting but thought that it was a little overkill since I know that all my polygons will be quads and that they are also all convex.

currently, I am splitting each quad into two triangles that share an edge and then checking if the point is on or in each of those two triangles using their areas.

for example
Triangle ABC and test point P.
if (areaPAB + areaPAC + areaPBC == areaABC) { return true; }

This seems like it may run a little slow since I need to calculate the area of 4 different triangles to run the check and if the first triangle of the quad returns false, I have to get 4 more areas. (I include a bit of an epsilon in the check to make up for floating point errors)

I'm hoping that there is an even faster way that might involve a single check of a point against a quad rather than splitting it into two triangles.

I've attempted to reduce the number of checks by putting the polygon's into an array[,]. When adding a polygon, it checks the minimum and maximum x and y values and then using those, places the same poly into the proper array positions. When checking a point against the available polygons, it retrieves the proper list from the array of lists.

I've been searching through similar questions and I think what I'm using now may be the fastest way to figure out if a point is in a triangle, but I'm hoping that there's a better method to test against a quad that is always convex. Every polygon test I've looked up seems to be testing against a polygon that has many sides or is an irregular shape.

Thanks for taking the time to read my long winded question to what's prolly a simple problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that fastest methods are:

1: Find mutual orientation of all vector pairs (DirectedEdge-CheckedPoint) through cross product signs. If all four signs are the same, then point is inside

Addition: for every edge

```
EV[i] = V[i+1] - V[i], where V[] - vertices in order
PV[i] = P - V[i]
Cross[i] = CrossProduct(EV[i], PV[i]) = EV[i].X * PV[i].Y - EV[i].Y * PV[i].X
```

Cross[i] value is positive, if point P lies in left semi-plane relatively to i-th edge (V[i] - V[i+1]), and negative otherwise. If all the Cross[] values are positive, then point p is inside the quad, vertices are in counter-clockwise order. f all the Cross[] values are negative, then point p is inside the quad, vertices are in clockwise order. If values have different signs, then point is outside the quad.

If quad set is the same for many point queries, then *dmuir* suggests to precalculate uniform line equation for every edge. Uniform line equation is a * x + b * y + c = 0. (a, b) is normal vector to edge. This equation has important property: sign of expression 
(a * P.x + b * Y + c) determines semi-plane, where point P lies (as for crossproducts)

2: Split quad to 2 triangles and use vector method for each: express CheckedPoint vector in terms of basis vectors.

```
P = a*V1+b*V2
```

point is inside when a,b>=0 and their sum <=1

Both methods require about 10-15 additions, 6-10 multiplications and 2-7 comparisons (I don't consider floating point error compensation)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried your second method and it's fewer calculations than the current method I'm using but just barely. I was hoping you might explain your first method a bit more and maybe I could use it in conjunction with storing the equation of the edges as mentioned by dmuir to see if I can't get better results.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on your original post. I've applied your formula and it seems to be running faster than the other method but I've run into a problem. I need for the check to return true even if a point is laying on an edge and not just within them. Is there any way I could adjust for that using an epsilon somewhere? The way I've got it implemented currently is as follows.

Comment: Since I will always and only ever will have 4 points in the polygon, instead of [i] I just manually declare and fill the four EV and PV and do the same using floats for the Cross results. I then check to see if all 4 of the cross results are all > 0 or < 0. It seems like changing the check against 0 to a small number seems to work but I'm wondering if this is an incorrect way to go about it. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Since we only need the sign in approach 1, a couple of tiny optimisations would be to compare EV[i].X * PV[i].Y directly to  EV[i].Y * PV[i].X without diffing first and checking sign after (may or may not compile to the same instructions), and quitting once one sign differs from the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If you could afford to store, with each quad, the equation of each of its edges then you could save a little time over MBo's answer.

For example if you have an inward pointing normal vector N for each edge of the quad, and a constant d (which is N.p for one of the vertcies p on the edge) then a point x is in the quad if and only if N.x >= d for each edge. So thats 2 multiplications, one addition and one comparison per edge, and you'll need to perform up to 4 tests per point.This technique works for any convex polygon.

Comment: Would this test also allow points that are on the line itself to register as within the polygon? And could you please break down what I would have to do for each edge to store it prior to checking against the test point?